# Am I using the wrong standard for JSON response?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am trying to build a simple todo application using it. I have designed a module called TodoServices in which I am creating a User service using the factory method. The code looks something like:

```
angular.module('TodoServices', ["ngResource"])
    .factory('User', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users/:id');
    });
```

The code in my app.js looks like:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', ['TodoServices']);

angularApp.controller('UsersController', function(User){
    this.users = {};
    this.users = User.query();
});
```

When I run my application, I get this error: [Error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=query&p1=array&p2=object)

I think this is because my web service is returning an object which not only has the data but also has a few other things such as a status and messages. Now Is it a wrong way of doing it? Should I just return the array from the back end? What is the actual problem here and how to solve this?

Comment: what data is returned? .query should return an array, but http://todoapi.rohanchhabra.in/users/:id probably returns just object

Comment: jsfiddle would be quite useful in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your error link says:

> By default, all resource actions expect objects, except query which expects arrays.

You should use an other function like User.Get() when you're not expecting an array but just a single object.